# Unable to install Nginx amplify on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have been trying to install nginx amplify agent on my ubuntu server but it keeps throwing this error :

```
 E: Package 'nginx-amplify-agent' has no installation candidate.
```

Here's what i have tried:

1) curl -L -O https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-amplify-agent/raw/master/packages/install.sh

2) API_KEY='key' sh ./install.sh

But the issues persists

I have also tried to run `apt-get update`

Comment: You can try [manual](https://amplify.nginx.com/docs/guide-installing-and-managing-nginx-amplify-agent.html#installing-the-agent-manually) installation.

Comment: How can i do that please ?

Comment: I give you a link with detailed instruction. I never installed amplify manually, so it is just a guess.

Comment: Alright thanks, awaiting the link

Comment: The link was in the first comment :)

Comment: @IvanShatsky thank you for the link, it's not still working